# Why does penguin.local point to an odd IP, when it is meant to be local?

Tags: networking

So I was doing some configuration for ssh. When I later then did this command:

```
lsof -i tcp|grep ^ssh
```

I got a list of what I was expecting to happen. However, something I never noticed before was that everything was being called "penguin.local" as my machine. This isn't odd, because I know I named my laptop as "penguin" and usually ".local" gets appended in ubuntu from past experience. The odd part is, why is it resolving to this IP address "5.16.138.166"? Surely it should say "127.0.0.1", like localhost, local, etc... can anyone help me?

Here's some commands I've ran if it might help:

```
$traceroute penguin.local
traceroute to penguin.local (5.16.138.166), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  penguin.local (5.16.138.166)  0.035 ms  0.010 ms  0.009 ms

$ ping penguin.local
PING penguin.local (5.16.138.166) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from penguin.local (5.16.138.166): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from penguin.local (5.16.138.166): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from penguin.local (5.16.138.166): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from penguin.local (5.16.138.166): icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
^C
--- penguin.local ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.050/0.054/0.007 ms

$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.050/0.053/0.057/0.007 ms
```

`whois` resolves to an address in "St.Petersburg" for some reason... yet from what I can see its a local address based on my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5.16.138.166 will be the IP address assigned to one of your local network interfaces.

Also, Not sure why your network is using that IP subnet as it doesn't appear to be assigned for use as a LAN subnet and in fact appears to be assigned for use on the internet.

```
daniel@daniel-desktop:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:0f:21:d6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.97  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe0f:21d6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:911590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:426938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1212763085 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:53171838 (53.1 MB)
          Interrupt:53 Base address:0xa000 

daniel@daniel-desktop:~$ ping daniel-desktop.local
PING daniel-desktop.local (192.168.0.97) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from daniel-desktop.local (192.168.0.97): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
```

Comment: Oh! Nice catch! I did ifconfig too, but thought nothing of it cos I quickly scanned through it... looking now I see this result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1390704/ what is that?

Comment: Ah wait, I think I know what that is... it could be to do with hamachi. Is this really required? Should this even be open, when hamachi isn't? How can I remove it?

Comment: Yes this is hamachi virtual interface.
Not sure if you can stop it using hamachi interface for the .local domain. But you could remove hamachi if you don't need it `sudo apt-get remove logmein-hamachi`


However, Having the .local domain resolve to that IP address shouldn't cause you any issues that I can think of.

Comment: I could never get hamachi to work properly, so I think I can safely remove that. Still think its strange that its attaching that IP to the .local domain name, doesn't really make sense... but at least I know what it is now! I was going nuts trying to figure out which config file or process was causing it.